# how to get skin url [attr()] from js file in magento

Tags: magento

For example on hover I want to change small image to thumbnail is it possible please don't say to change any code on `list.phtml`

```
$j('.foo').hover(function(){
    $j(this).attr('src','<?php echo $this->helper(catalog/image)->init($_product, thumbnail) ?>');

});
```

Comment: .a is a class ? or the tag?

Comment: class not tag..doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

try that..

```
<?php Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
    $j('#product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>').hover(function(){
        $j(this).attr('src','<?php echo Mage::helper(catalog/image)->init($_product, thumbnail) ?>');

    });
```

Comment: where are you getting this $_product; is  this for every product or single product?

Comment: it is for every product

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: problem is i don't know how to get skin url inside .attr() function  other wise this code is working from list.phtml

Comment: <?php echo $this->getSkinUrl()?> this will get the skin url

Comment: with current product id not only skin url if i can't get current product id then how can i'll change image on hover

Comment: i think you want current product image url?

Comment: yes current product image url inside attr() function hope u understand

Comment: <?php echo Mage::helper(catalog/image)->init($_product, thumbnail) ?> use this code in attr

Comment: nothing happen on hover i use this code inside attr() function ,also called in footer not working

Comment: updated the question and kindly check the console for js error.

Comment: did you load the product in foreach or not?

Comment: upload ur full code are foreach all the product or just using $_product;